# Analytic K-Homology (Higson, Roe) - Exercise 8.8.8

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces, c-star-algebras, k-theory

I am trying to understand the proof of Proposition 8.3.16 (***) in Higson and Roe's Analytic K-Homology book. They rely on Exercise 8.8.8 (which is the only argument I don't fully understand). It goes as follows:

Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra, $\rho:A\rightarrow \mathbb{B}(H)$ a representation of $A$ on a (separable, multigraded) Hilbert space $H$. Define
$$ \mathcal{D}_\rho(A)=\{T\in\mathbb{B}(H)\;:\;[T,\rho(a)]\sim0,\;\;\;\forall a\in A\},$$
and
$$\mathcal{D}_{\rho}(A//A)=\{T\in \mathcal{D}_{\rho}(A)\;:\;T\rho(a)\sim0\sim\rho(a)T,\;\;\;\forall a\in A\}, $$
where $T\sim S$ if and only if $T-S\in\mathbb{K}(H)$.

**Exercise 8.8.8:** Suposse $P\in\mathcal{D}_{\rho}(A)$ is self-adjoint and that $\rho(a)P\rho(a^*)$ is positive modulo compact operators for every $a\in A$. Prove that $P$ is positive modulo $\mathcal{D}_{\rho}(A//A)$.

The book provides a hint: since $P$ is self-adjoint, we can write $P=P_+-P_-$, where $P_{\pm}$ are positive and $P_+P_-=P_-P+=0$. Following this line of reasoning, the idea would be to show that $P_-\in\mathcal{D}_{\rho}(A//A)$. I have tried computing
$$ \langle \rho(a)P_-x,\rho(a)P_-x\rangle,$$
for some $x\in H$, with the hope that I could prove this vanishes modulo compacts, but to no avail.

(***)- Disclaimer: the reason why I also explicted this result is because in that setting one might use that the representation $\rho$ is non-degenerate (Lemma 8.3.8), meaning that $\overline{\rho(A)}H$ is dense in $H$, although Exercise 8.8.8 appears to be true in the more general picture.

Comment: @Aweygan Well-spotted, I will change that shortly!

Comment: I'm not sure about directly showing that $P_-\in \mathcal{D}_{\rho}(A//A)$, but one can adapt the proof of Lemma 2.1.18 in [this book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-0449-7) to obtain the result.

Comment: @Aweygan Thank you! I will take a look and perhaps if someone else doesn't write the answer down, I will :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\rho(a^*) P_- P_- \rho(a)= P_-\ \rho(a^*) P_- \rho(a) + [\rho(a^*), P_-]\rho(a)$$
The first term is zero module compacts, the second is also compact. This means that $(P_-\rho(a))^* (P_-\rho(a))$ is compact, so $P_-\rho(a)$ is so as well. Do the same trick with compact commutators to get that $\rho(a)P_-$ is compact. So $P_-$ is in $D(A//A)$.

Comment: I cannot see why the summands on the RHS should be compact, could you clarify that? (Also, I believe there is a little typo: the second summan should read "$[\rho(a^*),P_-]{\bf P_-}\rho(a)$"?

Comment: $[\rho(a^*), P_-] $ is compact because $P_-$ is in $\mathcal D_\rho(A)$. $\rho(a^*)P_-\rho(a)$ is the negative part of $\rho(a^*)P\rho(a)$, but this negative part is compact by the assumptions of the exercise. You are correct that an extra $P_-$ is missing, but that doesn't change compactness. I wrote the answer on a tablet, thats why it had to be so terse.

Comment: Okay, I see why the first summand in the RHS is compact now, but is it true that $P\in\mathcal{D}_{\rho}(A)$ implies $P_-\in\mathcal{D}_{\rho}(A)$?

Comment: Because $\mathcal D_\rho(A)$ is a C* sub-algebra of $B(H)$ (either verify all conditions directly or note that you have that $\mathcal D_\rho(A) = \pi^{-1} (\pi(\rho(A)')$ is the pre-image under $\pi: B(H)\to B(H)/K(H)$ of the commutant of $\pi(\rho(A))$ in the Calkin algebra $B(H)/K(H)$. Pre-images of C* algebras are C* and commutants of C* algebras also are C*)

Comment: I think I got it: since $P_+$ and $P_-$ are in the algebra generated by $P$, it follows that $P_-\in\mathcal{D}_{\rho}(A)$, right?

Comment: Yes, getting the positive and negative parts of an operator is something that happens entirely in the C* sub-algebra generated by this operator.